# fix wget "invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character"

Tags: wget

Wget show me `Can't write to ... (invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character)` when i try to dump a website with Persian or Arabic characters in urls.
Have wget any flag to fix this characters automatically?

> Update:

I tried this command:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p --restrict-file-names=windows --random-wait --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites http://site.tld
```

Comment: I don't know.. but what if you try cmd /u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading wget's [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-file-names_002c-restrict) suggests that `nocontrol` rather than `windows` might work better.  However, another question *[wget unicode filename errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010251/wget-unicode-filename-errors)* indicates that it does not, due to a [known problem](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?37564) with `wget`.  So there may be no easy solution.